# haskell Learn you a haskell chapter 4 example confusing

Tags: haskell, built-in

So I started with Learn you a haskell and on chap 4 found and example which did not understand
The author writes a function to extract initials from first name and last name

```
initials :: String -> String -> String  
initials firstname lastname = [f] ++ ". " ++ [l] ++ "."  
    where (f:_) = firstname  
          (l:_) = lastname
```

whats the meaning here.. she is combining a list of f with period and list of l and period.. how is she using the helper function? Has she taken (f:_) = firstname because f is the first letter of firstname?  Isnt using the head function on both words simpler?

Comment: `(f:_) = firstname` matches on the first character in `firstname`. As you know, strings in haskell are lists of characters. So `f` becomes first character of `firstname` and `l` becomes first character of `lastname`. Then she puts `f` and `l` in `[]` again to make them strings (because they have become characters) to be able to contatenate them with `". "`... which are strings.

Comment: Thanks.. so if i had used name and surname as two arguments would i have to use (n:_) = name and (s:_) = surname ??

Comment: no they are just variable names. The where clause is pattern matching.

Comment: thank you... I felt that you have to use the first letter of the variable that you use.. Thanks for clarifying

Comment: Yes, you could have written `where f = head firstname`. However, that somewhat "hides" the fact that it will fail if `firstname` is the empty string. `(f:_) = firstname` will fail, too, in that case, but it is perhaps more explicit, since you *see* that you are assuming the list is constructed with `:`, not `[]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A more understandable way of writing the same thing is

```
initials firstname lastname = case (firstname, lastname) of
    (f:_, l:_) -> [f] ++ ". " ++ [l] ++ "."
```

There's no helper function in the original code, only helper *variables* `f, l :: Char`.

Actually the preferred way of writing this is to not even introduce `firstname` and `lastname`, but simply pattern-match on them right there:

```
initials (f:_) (l:_) = [f] ++ ". " ++ [l] ++ "."
```

Note also that we still need to handle the case of either list being empty.

```
initials fn [] = ...?
initials [] ln = ...?
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the helper variable bit also..

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using the `head` function is simpler:

```
initials :: String -> String -> String  
initials firstname lastname = [head firstname] ++ ". " ++ [head lastname] ++ "."
```

But `[head x] == take 1 x` when it works, while `head`  errors for empty inputs and `take 1` doesn't, just returning an empty list in such case. So it's preferable to use `take 1` here:

```
initials :: String -> String -> String  
initials firstname lastname = take 1 firstname ++ ". " ++ take 1 lastname ++ "."
```